Rational canonical form of a matrix over finite fields
I wonder if the following statement is true:
If $A, B$ are $17 \times 17$ matrices over the field $\mathbb{F}_3$ such that they have the same characteric polynomial and minimal polynomial. $A$ has no eigenvalue in $\mathbb{F}_3$ and rank of $f(A)$ equals rank of $f(B)$ for all irreducible polynomials $f \in \mathbb{F}_3[x]$, then $A,B$ are similar.
I have no clue how to prove it or give a counterexample. Any hint is appreciated!

You should prove they have the same frobenius decomposition or try to prove it. The assertion about the ranks and characteristic and minimal polynomial is enough I believe but I’m not sure

@julio_es_sui_glace The issue I got is that I do not know how to use the condition on irreducible polynomials. If it is for all polynomials, then it is easy. Since when we compute the block numbers, we need to calculate something like rank of $f^k(A)$, where $f^k$ is not irreducible.

Using the Frobenius decomposition, you can find a counterexample with:
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
C_{p^2}\\
& C_{p^2}\\
&&C_{p^3}\\
&&&C_q
\end{pmatrix}
\qquad
\text{and}
\qquad
B=\begin{pmatrix}
C_p\\
&C_{p^3}\\
&&C_{p^3}\\
&&&C_q
\end{pmatrix}$$
With
$$\begin{align*}
p \in &\{x^2+1,x^2-x+1\} \\
q \in &\begin{Bmatrix} x^3 -x + 1, x^3 -x - 1, x^3+x^2-1,x^3+x^2+x-1,x^3-x^2+1,\\
x^3+x^2-x+1,x^3-x^2+x+1,x^3-x^2-x-1 \end{Bmatrix}
\end{align*}$$
and $C_r$ the companion matrix associated to $r$: if $r = x^k - a_{k-1}x^{k-1} - \cdots - a_1 x - a_0$, we have
$$C_r = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & a_0\\
1 & 0 & & 0  & a_1\\
0 & 1& \ddots & \vdots & \vdots\\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & 0& a_{k-2}\\
0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 & a_{k-1}
\end{pmatrix}$$
They both have $\mu_A = \mu_B = p^3q$, $\chi_A = \chi_B = p^7q$.
They don't have any eigenvalues in $\mathbb{F}^3$ since they are irreducible.
Now to study the rank of $f(A)$ for $f$ irreducible we can just add up the rank of the $f(C_{r})$ by restricting on the respective subspace they stabilise.
Now the subspaces associated to the $C_{r}$ have a basis given by $\{v,C_rv,\dots,C_r^{\deg r - 1}v\} $ for some cyclic vector $v$ (in the case of the companion matrix it is just $e_1$), so solving $f(C_{r}) w = 0$ is just solving $fs(C_{r})(v)=0$ for $\deg s < \deg r $.
But we know that $\mu_{C_{r}}^v = r$ (the minimal polynomial relative to $v$) so this means $r \mid fs$.

Case 1 $f^r=1$, then $r \mid s$ thus
$$\ker f(C_r) = \{0\}$$
and
$$\operatorname{rk} f(C_{r}) = \deg r.$$
Case 2 $f\mid r$ and since we work only with powers of irreducible polynomials, $r= f^m$ thus $f^{m-1} \mid s$.
We have $s=f^{m-1}t$ with $\deg t < m \deg f - (m-1)\deg f = \deg f$, this means
$$\dim \ker f(C_{p^m}) = \deg f$$
thus
$$\operatorname{rk} f(C_{f^m}) = (m-1)\deg f.$$

This means all the conditions are required, since
$$\operatorname{rk} p(A) = 2 \cdot (1+1+2) + 3 = 11 = 2\cdot (0+2+2) + 3 = \operatorname{rk} p(B)
\\
\operatorname{rk} q(A) = 2 \cdot (2+2+3) + 3 \cdot 0 = 14 = 2\cdot (1+3+3) + 3\cdot 0 = \operatorname{rk} q(B)$$
and for every irreducible $r$ different of $q,p$ we have
$$\operatorname{rk} r(A) = 17.$$
This means that $A$ and $B$ meet all the conditions and we don't have $A \sim B$ since their Frobenius decomposition is different.

This example is equivalent to the example of @Sassatelli-Giulio, it was originally not equivalent but it was due to a mistake. You can easily show that all the counterexample have these Frobenius decompositions.

This gives you $2\cdot 8 = 16$ choice of pairs $\{p,q\}$ of counterexamples (up to matrix conjugation).
If you choose to work with $\mathbb{F}_r$, you will have $\dfrac{r^2-r}{2}\cdot \dfrac{r^3-r}{3}$ choices of pairs.
And if you want to change the dimension $n$, you can have $n= 14$ or $n \geq 16$.
Remark: In general, you condition is fulfilled when for each $p\mid \mu$ irreducible:

$\deg p \neq 1$, i.e. no block matrix of size 1.
the dominant block (i.e. the $C_{p^M}$ where $M$ is the greatest) is the same in each decomposition.
the dimension of $\ker p^m (A)$ and $\ker p^m(B)$ is the same (i.e. the sum of the $m$ for each block $C_{p^m}$).
the number of blocks of the form $C_{p^m}$ is the same.


@SassatelliGiulio You're right, I need to remove some, replacing $p^4$ by $p^3$ should do it

Ah but this will give the same example as below

Thank you! Very detailed answer!

$\newcommand{rk}{\operatorname{rk}}$Call $p_X$ the characteristic polynomial of a matrix $X$, and $\mu_X$ the minimal polynomial. Call $X\oplus Y$ the block matrix $\begin{bmatrix}X &0\\ 0 &Y\end{bmatrix}$. We have $p_{X\oplus Y}=p_Xp_Y$, $\mu_{X\oplus Y}=\operatorname{lcm}(\mu_X,\mu_Y)$, $\dim\ker(X\oplus Y)=\dim\ker X+\dim\ker Y$ and $\rk(X\oplus Y)=\rk X+\rk Y$.
Call $V=\begin{bmatrix}0&-1\\ 1&0\end{bmatrix}$. $\mu_V=p_V=x^2+1$, which is irreducible. Then call $J(V,n)=\begin{bmatrix}V & I &0&\cdots&0\\ 0&V & I&&\vdots\\ \vdots &&\ddots &&\vdots\\ 0&&&V&I\\0&\cdots&\cdots&0&V \end{bmatrix}$. We have $\mu_{J(V,n)}=p_{J(V,n)}=(x^2+1)^n$ and $\rk((J(V,n)^2+I)^k)=\max\{2n-2k,0\}$.
Let $W_1=J(V,1)\oplus J(V,3)\oplus J(V,3)$ and $W_2=J(V,2)\oplus J(V,2)\oplus J(V,3)$. They're $14\times 14$ matrices such that:

$\mu_{W_1}=\mu_{W_2}=(x^2+1)^3$;
$p_{W_1}=p_{W_2}=(x^2+1)^8$;
$\rk (W^2_1+I)=2-2+6-2+6-2=8=4-2+4-2+6-2=\rk(W_2^2+I)$
$\rk(f(W_1))=\rk(f(W_2))=14$ for all irreducible polynomials of $\Bbb F_3[x]$ that don't divide its characteristic polynomial (in this case, all except $x^2+1$);
$W_1$ isn't similar to $W_2$ because $\rk((W_1^2+I)^2)=4$ and $\rk((W_2^2+I)^2)=2$.
they have no eigenvalues in $\Bbb F_3$.

To obtain a $17\times 17$ counterexample that retains all those properties, take $A=W_1\oplus U$ and $B=W_2\oplus U$ for some $U$ such that $\mu_U$ is irreducible of degree $3$.

I never thought of the $C_{p^m}$ as generalised Jordan matrices $J(p,m)$ like this, this is a nice idea!

Thank you! The Jordan generalization looks inspiring.
